# How to write -> operator correctly when you only have a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is a repro case:

```
#include <iostream>

template< class MessageType >
class Augmented
{
public:
    Augmented( const MessageType& message ) 
        : m_message( message )
    {}

    const MessageType* operator->() const { return &m_message; }

private:
    const MessageType& m_message;
};

template< class MessageType >
Augmented<MessageType> augmented( MessageType&& message )
{
    return Augmented<MessageType>( std::forward<MessageType>(message) );
}

class Test
{
public:
    void print() const {  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    Test test;

    auto augmented_test = augmented( test );
    augmented_test->print();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using VS2011 (update 1).
When I try to use code that use the -> operator, I get this error:

> error C2528: '->' : pointer to reference is illegal

I understand the error, but what I don't find is how to avoid it in this specific case.
I just need a pointer to the object inferred by the member reference. I tried several different syntaxes which all resulted in the same error.

Any idea how to write this operator correctly?

---

Note to keep the focus on the question: I'm voluntarly using a reference to avoid a copy that should never occur in the very specific and isolated context this helper code is used; the question isn't about the design of the class.

---

LAST EDIT: replaced the question code with a full repro case. DeadMG is spot on so I accept his answer. To be more precise: the helper function (augmented()) forward MessageType as `Test&` instead of `Test`, which is wrong. There are several ways to fix this, the simplest being to make the helper function not forwarding the type but just take a `const MesssageType&`.

Comment: Looks good to me. The error is unrelated to your reference. How are you using the operator?

Comment: Right, updated with more infos.

Comment: But with the wrong info. This code still works. Could you create an MWE?

Comment: Yes sorry, I added how the function is called, I think the problem migh t be the helper function...

Comment: [Works for me.](http://www.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c2f2fb77220a3010d3f6bfd9f123f96f) Now, the MWE would be really helpful please.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You didn't use a helper function, which is where the problem comes from.

Comment: If you had shown the whole error, it would have told us what `MessageType` was.

Comment: @DeadMG True, sorry I didn't have that reflex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is quite legal for any particular value type. However, I suspect that you have instantiated it with a reference. This would lead to `const MessageType*` expanding to `const (T&)*`, which is not legal. You need to check that the template parameter is not a reference.

Comment: `const typename std::remove_reference<MessageType>type* operator->() const { return &m_message; }` maybe.  (`#include <type_traits>`, C++11 header, pretty common nowadays)

Comment: @DeadNG I added the calling code and the helper function I use to create the object.

Comment: @DeadMG I think the helpfer function to create the object might be wrong... maybe removing the perfect forwarding? Or even removing the function...

Comment: @DeadMG: ha ha, you *guessed wrong* about the calling code. now the OP has added it, the problem is exposed as simply calling `o->m` where `o` is not a pointer. lol :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ? He was correct. I don't understand your remark. The problem was the MessageType being a reference instead of a type.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't see the function